What is the significance of John using the accusative, θεόν and then the nominative θεὸς for God in the same verse?

In the beginning was the Word, and the Word was with God, and the Word was God. (John 1:1 ESV)
ἐν ἀρχῇ ἦν ὁ λόγος καὶ ὁ λόγος ἦν πρὸς τὸν θεόν καὶ θεὸς ἦν ὁ λόγος

John begins with three statements about the Word (a) The Word was in the beginning (b) The Word was with God (c) The Word was God. In each the Word is written as nominative ὁ λόγος and is treated as the subject. In the second statement this is clear as God is accusative. However, in the third statement both Word and God are nominative.
About θεὸς ἦν ὁ λόγος A.T. Robertson states the article indicates is ὁ λόγος is the subject:

The subject is made plain by the article (ο λογος) and the predicate without it (θεος) just as in John 4:24 πνευμα ο θεος can only mean "God is spirit," not "spirit is God." So in 1 John 4:16 ο θεος αγαπη εστιν can only mean "God is love," not "love is God."

How John uses "God" in the complete verse strikes me as unusual. The first use (b) is accusative and follows the basic sentence construction where the subject is nominative, ὁ λόγος, and object is accusative τὸν θεόν. If ὁ λόγος is the subject in the third statement, why not continue to write God as accusative θεόν?
My question is two part. First, wouldn't all of these statements treat the Word as subject and God as object in English?

θεὸς ἦν ὁ λόγος
τὸν θεόν ἦν ὁ λόγος
θεόν ἦν ὁ λόγος
ὁ λόγος ἦν τὸν θεόν
ὁ λόγος ἦν θεόν

Second, if any or all do convey the same subject-object, what is the significance to John's choice of using the nominative for God rather than the accusative (ὁ λόγος ἦν θεόν as an example)?

Since the Greek article can often be considered as the demonstrative pronoun (from which it developed, see Daniel B Wallace) then the translation may be seen as 'and God was that Word'. Which makes far more sense than many other translations. The article locates a concept which is previously identified by a noun. (Again, see Daniel B Wallace 'Beyond the Basics'). The English (speaking) mind does not readily accept this word order but it is John's word order and the emphasis he makes ought to be respected. 'Subject' 'object' and 'predicate' should give place to the emphasis of the apostle.

There are some rather basic rules of grammar involved in John 1:1 with its three clauses.

A preposition governs the accusative: the second clause πρὸς ("with") governs the accusative Θεόν.
The verb "to be" (= εἰμί/ἦν) takes the same case (nominative) after as before, hence giving a nominative predicate.  Thus, in the third clause, both must be nominative, but logos has the article and must be the subject.

This third clause, correctly translated as "The Word was God" is a Greek logic category statement - The "Word" is in the category of "God".

οὗτος ἦν ὃν John 1:15

@RevelationLad - that is a different construction again - ὃν is the relative pronoun with a subsequent verb εἶπον and thus must be accusative.

@RevelationLad I'm glad you asked that question of Dottard before you asked it of me because that construction is confusing.

Since the Greek article can often be considered as the demonstrative pronoun (from which it developed, see Daniel B Wallace) then the translation may be seen as 'and God was that Word'.
Which makes far more sense than many other translations.
The article locates a concept which is previously identified by a noun. (Again, see Daniel B Wallace 'Beyond the Basics').
The English (speaking) mind does not readily accept this word order but it is John's word order and the emphasis he makes ought to be respected. 'Subject' 'object' and 'predicate' should give place to the emphasis of the apostle.

It seems like you're answering a different question than what was asked.

The analysis of John’s use of θεόν (accusative) and θεὸς (nominative) in John 1:1, combined with the advanced interpretation of the verb ἦν as "to dwell," provides a refined theological and linguistic understanding of the text.

The Use of the Accusative (τὸν θεόν):
In Greek, the accusative often denotes the direct object of a relationship. In "ὁ λόγος ἦν πρὸς τὸν θεόν" ("the Logos was with God"), the accusative τὸν θεόν points to a relationship of closeness or interaction with a distinct entity, identified here as God. The preposition πρὸς further emphasizes an intimate and dynamic relationship, often rendered as "face to face with." This underscores that the Logos was in unique communion with God.

The Use of the Nominative (θεὸς):
The second occurrence, "θεὸς ἦν ὁ λόγος" ("and the Logos was God"), uses θεὸς in the nominative, which typically indicates the subject or the predicate nominative. Here, θεὸς serves as a predicate nominative of ὁ λόγος, emphasizing the nature or essence of the Logos as divine. The nominative highlights the central claim of the verse: the divine identity of the Logos.

The Advanced Meaning of ἦν (To Dwell):
If ἦν is interpreted as "to dwell," this implies that God (θεὸς) dwelled in the Logos, suggesting an ontological and spiritual unity. While the Logos is distinct in relation to τὸν θεόν, it fully possesses the essence of divinity. This idea is echoed later in John 1:14, where the Logos "became flesh and dwelled among us" (ἐσκήνωσεν ἐν ἡμῖν). The verb ἦν in the context of Exodus 20:21 is explained by 1 Kings 8:12, acquiring an advance in linguistic meaning from “being” to “dwelling”, which is again in agreement with New Testament Theology regarding the Logos and Patristic Theology regarding recent Christianity

The Logical and Theological Flow of the Verse:



"ἐν ἀρχῇ ἦν ὁ λόγος": Introduces the Logos as existing from the beginning, with ἦν pointing to the continuity of its existence.
"καὶ ὁ λόγος ἦν πρὸς τὸν θεόν": Highlights the relationship of the Logos with God, suggesting personal distinction and intimate communion.
"καὶ θεὸς ἦν ὁ λόγος": Affirms that the essence of God dwelled in the Logos, establishing the Logos as fully God.

The use of the accusative and nominative in John 1:1, paired with the advanced understanding of ἦν as "to dwell," reveals the theological depth of the verse. John articulates that the Logos existed in intimate communion with God while simultaneously being the full embodiment of divine essence. This foundational statement underpins the Christian doctrine of the Trinity, presenting the Logos as both fully divine and eternally relational with the Father.

ἦν (To Dwell) — No.

The verb ἦν in the context of Exodus 20:21 has the meaning of dwelling, it is not impossible to also have it in John 1:1

Thank you. 1. WRT to πρὸς τὸν θεόν, what you say makes sense. I would think the emphasis is on πρὸς which causes τὸν θεόν. You seem to be saying it is τὸν θεόν which brings πρὸς. 2. The use of ἦν vs some other verb is a different aspect from what I am asking. 3. Are you able to include what I am asking WRT to John 1:1c? Could John have used the accusative there and if so, what is the difference between saying the Word was God (nominative vs accusative).

@Betho's—Again, no. Exodus 20:21 has the relative adverb οὗ (“where”) modifying the finite verb ἦν. In John 1:1, ἦν is functioning as a copula (copulative verb) linking the predicate nominative θεὸς to the subject ὁ λόγος. You are comparing two entirely different grammatical syntaxes.

Although both cases involve the verb ἦν, the syntax is different but not completely disconnected. In Exodus 20:21, the relative adverb οὗ indicates a location, linking the verb ἦν to a specific place, while in John 1:1, ἦν functions as a copula, connecting the subject ὁ λόγος to the predicate θεὸς. What they have in common is that ἦν serves to establish a relationship of predication, whether locational (Exodus) or existential/identitary (John). The difference lies in the type of predicate: one is locational, and the other is existential/identifying.
